# TFS With Jira - Any tools?

Tags: tfs, jira

I'm looking at integrating TFS with JIRA. I Want to run my test cases in TFS but when i raise bugs i want them to automatically update on the JIRA board. Is there anything out there that can make this possible?

Also would it automatically block the test case and link the bug in JIRA with it?

Comment: TaskTop springs to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such kind of build in feature or extension. However, you could raise bugs in TFS/Azure DevOps first when you run your test cases. Then synchronize your bugs with issues in Jira. It's not able to directly link the bug in JIRA with TFS test cases.

You could choose to use [TFS4JIRA Azure DevOps integration](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/42296/tfs4jira-azure-devops-integration?hosting=server&tab=overview&_ga=2.128270988.1262855053.1574408724-889402998.1572500371).

> TFS4JIRA is migration, integration and synchronization tool, which
>   bridges TFS / Azure DevOps and Jira (Server/DC/Cloud).  Integrate
>   Azure DevOps with TFS4JIRA, to view your project or issue-associated
>   Azure DevOps check-ins in Jira, as well as synchronize changes made to
>   the issues and integrate Azure Jira work items.
>
> - Create your individual TFS4JIRA sync profiles and define the project    collections which you want to work with.
> - Map your issue types, work item types, fields, values.
> - Hierarchy and subtasks synchronisation supported.
> - Enable your profile and, voila! – the synchronizer is making sure    that Jira and Azure DevOps exchange information in the background.

If you already have some bug/issue work items in JIRA and want to import them to TFS on-premise server. There is an extension named Jira to Azure DevOps/TFS work item migration tool. It is used to Azure DevOps work item migration tool lets you export data from Jira and import it as work items in Azure DevOps or Microsoft Team Foundation Server. [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solidify.jira-devops-migration) is the download page.